# Run-time Error while using anorm in scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, anorm

I have tried to load some data from database using anorm. But I got following runtime error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: ColumnName(locations.Ref,Some(Ref))

Here is my Model class

```
package models
import play.api.db._
import play.api.Play.current

import anorm._
import anorm.SqlParser._

import scala.language.postfixOps
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

    case class Location(id: Int, name: String,ref:String,isactive:Int)


        object Location {

            /**
            * Parse a Location from a ResultSet
            */
            val loc = {
                get[Int]("Locations.Id") ~
                get[String]("Locations.Name")~
                get[String]("Locations.Ref")~
                get[Int]("Locations.Active") map {
                case id~name~ref~isactive => Location(id, name,ref,isactive)
                }
            }


             //Get All Locations from DB
              def findAllLocations():List[Location] = DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
                   SQL("SELECT Id,Name,Ref,Active from Locations").as(Location.loc *)
              }


}
```

Here is my table

[image]

Comment: Does this come without a cause exception and stack-traces?

Comment: yes. I couldn't`t found any reasonable cause for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

I have changed the code as follows  replace `get[String]("Locations.Ref")` for `get[Option[String]]("Locations.Ref")`

```
val loc = {
   get[Int]("Locations.Id") ~
   get[String]("Locations.Name")~
   get[Option[String]]("Locations.Ref")~
   get[Int]("Locations.Active") map {
   case id~name~ref~isactive => Location(id, name,ref,isactive)
   }
}
```

And also change the case class as `ref:String` to `ref:Option[String]`

```
 case class Location(id: Int, name: String,ref:Option[String],isactive:Int)
```

Comment: You can have a look at the [documentation](http://cchantep.github.io/anorm/#working-with-optionalnullable-values)